# Can DTOs be spring managed beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

I am using spring 3.0.

I have few DTOs. Can I declare them as spring beans? If so what should be the bean scope?

Comment: Yes, you could, but you usually wouldn't want to. The purpose of a DTO is to be a detached view of some item, so unless you're just passing around an initial configuration in some DTO, it's usually better to create a simple lookup or configuration service around whatever the DTO is representing.

Comment: Do you want them as managed by spring or do you want to create them on your own but inject dependencies into them?

Comment: If it's just for transfer they probably wouldn't have any external dependencies, so I'm not sure what the point would be, unless there's a specific use case you haven't described.

Comment: Any object can be made a spring bean, but there is no apparent reason why a DTO would benefit from becoming a spring bean. what was the problem that you where trying to solve? if you edit the question towards that, we could propose something concrete and it would probably be more helpful

Answer (score 3):

Usually, DTOs instantiation is not managed by spring (for instance Hibernate often instantiates DTOs).

Spring does have a `prototype` scope where a new object is created each time you lookup the object from the `ApplicationContext`. This scope is useful when you want to define default values in spring config.

See the documentation on prototype scope, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype).