# Spring bean configuration to use singleton or prototype?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am using Java7 and Spring3. I have below classes.

### Request.java

```
public interface Request {
  public void doProcess();

}
```

### RequestImpl.java

```
    @Transactional
    public class RequestImpl implements Request{

     private String name;
     private String age;

     //setters and getters

     public void doProcess(){

      //use name and age and call third party class which will save data into database

      }
}
```

### SpringConfig.xml

```
<bean id="request" class="pkg.RequestImpl.java" />
```

Now clients will use RequestImpl as below.

```
RequestImplreq = (RequestImpl)applicationContext.getBean("request");
req.setName("someName");
req.setAge("20");
req.doProcess();
```

Now my question is do  i need to declare above RequestImpl.java scope as prototype or singleton?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need `RequestImpl` to be a spring bean?

Comment: Rc, thanks for your reply. They have to be spring managed beans because i am using @Transactional. Just now i edited my question.

Comment: Its depends on your requirement if your user you want to share the same object you can declare it as singletone other wise if you want each user get new instance of RequestImpl then use prototype.

Comment: My advice, have an object for (name,age) and a dedicated processor (spring bean) and just pass the object to `doProcess` of the processor

Comment: Shekhar, above bean does not hold any state right? When a bean does not contain any state then it can be Singleton right?

Comment: RC, in above case can i declare my bean as singleton? If it is declared as prototype then does spring transactions work?

Comment: You may need synchronized doProcess() in case of singleton. If the doProcess() is timeconsuming and you have realy a lot of calls use prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you are not working well: processes and data to process should be separated ([Can DTOs be spring managed beans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833110/can-dtos-be-spring-managed-beans)) so `doProcess()` should be defined as `doProcess(name,age)` or shaded behind a factory or something similar.
Probably the best option is to define

```
public interface Request {
  public void doProcess(String name,String age);
}

@Transactional
public class RequestImpl implements Request{
  public void doProcess(String name,String age){
    // do what you want
  }
}
```

your SpringConfig.xml stay the same and call code will change to:

```
Request req= applicationContext.getBean(Request.class);
req.doProcess("someName", "20");
```

Beside all, perform a `ApplicationContext.getBean()` and cast result to an implementation is (usually) bad pratice because Spring can proxy returned object and cast to implementation will fail with a `ClassCastException`

Answer (score 0):

@user3269829 : By default the scope would be `singleton` now it is totally depend upon your requirement, if you want a bean object for every request then you can go for "`prototype`" and if you want to share single bean object among the multiple request then you can go for "`singleton`"

Comment: if prototype is used and many instances are created then does spring remove the instances again?

Comment: Spring framework takes care of it. You no need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your third party class is implemented. If you want to ensure a single instance of your class you can use factory-method of spring beans and ensure single instance.

Check ***"3.3.2.2 Instantiation with a static factory method"*** part of **[Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html)**

It should look like this in bean definition:

```
<!-- the factory bean, which contains a method called createInstance() -->
<bean id="serviceLocator" class="examples.DefaultServiceLocator">
  <!-- inject any dependencies required by this locator bean -->
</bean>

<!-- the bean to be created via the factory bean -->
<bean id="clientService"
      factory-bean="serviceLocator"
      factory-method="createClientServiceInstance"/>
```

and singleton creator:

```
public class DefaultServiceLocator {
  private static ClientService clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();
  private DefaultServiceLocator() {}

  public ClientService createClientServiceInstance() {
    return clientService;
  }
}
```